# Laravel login (auth()->attempt()) never returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

When I use auth() with attempt() using Tymon JWTAuth, I'm always getting an HTTP OK (200) as a result with the following code. The user is logged in in spite of invalid credentials, and even an empty database table.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

use App\Models\Member;

class Login extends Controller {
    public function login() {
        try {
            $creds = request(['email', 'password']);
            $token = auth()->guard('member')->attempt($creds);

            if (is_null($token)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
            }
        } catch (Exception $error) {
            Log::error('Error logging in!');
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error logging in!'], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'members',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],
        'member' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'members',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'members' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Member::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'members' => [
            'provider' => 'members',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

I've tried everything I can come to think of (still learning Laravel), and have used Google and ChatGPT trying to fix it. No dice.

I'm kinda expecting attempt() not to give a token when it shouldn't be able to validate the credentials.

Comment: How have you configured your `member` authentication guard?

Comment: auth.php now provided.

Comment: Can you dd($token) and check the result? At a glance, auth()->guard('member')->attempt($creds) is expected to return a boolean result in most cases, which means the token will never be null, and you will always get a 200.   check what the return value is. 
lastly can you verify Member model (App\Models\Member) extends Laravel's Authenticatable.

Comment: For some reason dd() doesn't output anything to my console. But I tried Log::debug($token), and it returns blank/nothing. When I Log::debug(gettype($token)), it returns "boolean". The JWTAuth docs says attempt() will "[...] return either a jwt or null", so why is it returning a blank boolean?